# get error on creating alert dialog build

Tags: android

i am trying to create an alert dialog builder in my activity. but for some reason when i use this in AlertDialog.Builder(this) it does not recognize "this" object.
even when i change it to getAppllicationContext() or getApplication() the application crashed.
this is my code:

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setTitle("Date Error!")
                    .setMessage("Date is not valid! Please select another date")
                    .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        }
                    })
                    .setIcon(R.drawable.error_32)
                    .show();
```

Comment: `AlertDialog.Builder` requires an Activity Context, so `getApplicationContext()` and `getApplication()` aren't going to work. Your posted code is apparently not directly in an Activity. If it's in a Fragment, use `getActivity()`. If not, you need to post more of the surrounding code.

Comment: You need a [Context](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html) as parameter to the constructor. Read more about [AlertDialog.Builder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your code looks somewhat like this:

```
class AlertClass extends Activity {
    ...setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override public void onClick(View v) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(...
        }
    });
}
```

Just do

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(AlertClass.this);
```